# Ubuntu 22.10 crashes on startup after a power failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, power-management, minecraft

I have a Dell Inspiron 3567 with Windows 11(original upgraded OS as it was Windows 10 when it was purchased), Windows 10(another OS) and Ubuntu 22.10. Up until the power failure, everything went smoothly. I was installing Lunar Client(a popular client for Minecraft) and had to install libfuse for it to work(as per the terminal) and after it working fine, my laptop lost AC power and shutdown almost immediately. When I try to boot it up, it boots up until it shows the Ubuntu logo and after that it shows me the programs checklist(the one you access by pressing Alt+F.) and crashes. Note that I can type at this stage. I dont have NVIDIA graphics, all Intel. I don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't included any boot logs...

Comment: In your situation (*after any unexpected shutdown or power off*) I always boot a *live* system and scan my drives for problems (ie. check SMART stats etc - hey it's what I do!) and most importantly for you, I then perform *file-system* checks, and if some are found & corrected; I'll then reboot & expect my system to boot normally. I'll suggest you boot *live* media & perform some file-system checks.